# how to match two table until table 1 row value match 3 times in table 2 columns

Tags: mysql

i have two table, table 1 as below

```
session                 status  SN          error_code
3f24197394c521349206a11 Fail    ACNW6676    40774,500005
7385122219fa35c37942511 Fail    ACNW6676    40555,40187,500004,500005
412afc12a33601011721415 Fail    ACNW6676    100001,500005
9213232191116c821a59f86 Fail    ACNW6676    500005
```

and table 2 as below

```
error
0001
500005
40774
```

if I want to table 2 (error) check against table 1 (error_code) if match 3 times will return 1.
for example,
500005 from table 2 match to table 1 (error_code) 3 times it display the error code and the number of matched.
and error from table 1 500005 and 40774 cannot sum the number of match. mean every single value from table 2 is separated

any idea for this?

result wanted:-

```
error  count
500005 4 
40774  1
```

if the count 3 and above return 1

Comment: what version of mysql are you using

Comment: i using,
protocol_version 10
version 5.0.77

Comment: can you also add the desired output as a text snippet

Comment: hi Haleemur,
added desired output at above.

Answer (score 1):

The *trick* here is the join between tables `table1` & `table2`.

Using `LIKE` with wildcards will not work.

example: this will not work as it will wrongly join `100001,500005` with `0001`.

```
...from table1 join table2 ON table1.error_code LIKE concat('%', table2.error, '%')
```

It is necessary instead to check that `table2.error` is contained in `table1.error_code` *as a whole word*. This can be expressed using regular expressions.

The regular expression where `\b` signifies a word-boundary

```
\bword\b
```

will match the text

```
this sentence has a word in it
```

but will not match the text

```
this sentence is made with words
```

mysql uses these markers instead to signify word boundaries

```
[[:<:]], [[:>:]]
```

Thus we construct our query as such

```
SELECT
    error
  , count(*) count 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
  ON error_code REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', error, '[[:>:]]') 
GROUP BY 1;
```

which *should* yield the rows:

```
+--------+----------+
| error  | count(*) |
+--------+----------+
| 40774  |        1 |
| 500005 |        4 |
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must be sure to organize your data!
If you're doing this in sql, you should write "40774,500005":

1. as a string, and so, treat this data
2. separate in other field, (as the numbers of items can vary, I'd recommend another table)

After doing that, it will only do the sql search.

Example:

```
SELECT error, count(*) count FROM table1 JOIN table2 GROUP BY 1;
```